# Jquery Mobile - Can I use it with existing layout?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a web site template that I really like but I want to use some of jquery mobiles functionality such as their page transitions. Can I use my existing website template along with jquery mobile framework without doing anything extensive? The current template is made with html5 in mind along with jquery.

Jquery Mobile Im referring to is here:

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: I would ***always*** suggest you do a small 'redesign'/'modification' of your existing design for a pure ***mobile version*** of the same content. Like mentioned; Images, Videos, large amounts of content.. ect. are all things you want to avoid on the mobile page. *maybe that image gallery on the homepage is not a good idea for the mobile version*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 and jQuery are pretty much compatible for migration to a jQuery mobile scenario. If your controls are not complicated enough to be unworkable with fingers.

You should be fine as long as you make sure you simplify the content so users don't see a huge loads of content as they would on a normal screen. (But do give users the option of visiting the normal site).

Try to minimise sending images and videos down the line.

If you use external API's, sometimes they need alternative arrangement for their service to work on a mobile device. So study those.

And finally it is going to be a huge benefit to your career in supporing mobile devices if you [read this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/)

Comment: My current website is in html5.